# Is there any winapi call to get notify when an event occured

Tags: winapi, msdn

I am monitoring process activity on a windows machine. I got one useful link from MSDN saying important [Events to Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/appendix-l--events-to-monitor) with this information I started building a small piece of code using WINAPI call - [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) The code is below

But using this I am unable to get control when those event encountered which is listed on that link [Events to Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/appendix-l--events-to-monitor)

Can anyone please suggest, why I am not able to receive these mentioned events

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
 switch (iMsg)
 {
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        HWINEVENTHOOK st;

        // EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART
        st = SetWinEventHook(0x44E, 0x44E, NULL, WinEventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);


        break;
    }


    case WM_SHOWWINDOW:
    {
        //MessageBox(hwnd, L"WM_SHOWWINDOW", L"Message", MB_OK);
        break;
    }


    case WM_DESTROY:
    {

        PostQuitMessage(0);
        ExitProcess(0);
        break;
    }
 }

 return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


void CALLBACK WinEventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, LONG idChild, DWORD idEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{

 char buffer[100] = {"\0"};

 sprintf_s(buffer, "Event [%d]\n Handle [%p]\n idEventThread [%d]\n EventTime [%d]", event, hwnd, idEventThread, dwmsEventTime);

 MessageBoxA(hwnd, buffer, "Message", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: No.  Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer.  Those kind of events.  Start [reading here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/about-event-logging).

Comment: @HansPassant You mean, whatever MSDN mentioned (Link : Events_to_Monitor), that I can't use in program directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) ：Sets an event hook function for a range of
>   events.

About a range of events, please refer [Event Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants).

> This topic describes the events that are generated by the operating
>   system and by server applications. The constants are listed in
>   alphabetical order.
>
> Prior to using these events, client applications should use Accessible
>   Event Watcher to verify that these events are used by UI elements.
>
> For more information about events in general, see What Are WinEvents?
>   and System Level and Object Level Events. For more information about
>   the events sent by the system, see Appendix A: Supported User
>   Interface Elements Reference.

It can be said that `SetWinEventHook` is not so powerful. The events it can detect do not include [the malicious activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/appendix-l--events-to-monitor) you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Strive, I got more clarity about my question, your answer was more useful for me. I'll get to know these details which you have mentioned. 

One more thing I would like to ask you, how can I include those events [Appendix L: Events to Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/appendix-l--events-to-monitor) to be monitor using programmatically(winapi). I am not getting enough thread for this action.

Comment: @YuvrajTakey As Hans said that , no winapi can achieve this except using Event Viewer.

Comment: Okay, It means only one option left out is to monitor "EventViewer Log" for those (Appendix L: Events to Monitor) kinds of Events

Comment: @YuvrajTakey Yes. These events are not monitored by just a few APIs. They(Appendix L: Events to Monitor) involve a lot of knowledge that we may not touch.